# Soundcloud SDK - load track from url

Tags: javascript, sdk, soundcloud

So I did a tutorial on Soundcloud SDK through CodeAcademy [here](https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/javascript-intermediate-en-txGOj/0/1) and wanted to take the knowledge I learned from that and put it on Codepen. But I want to use a different track than the one they use in this tutorial - specifically this song https://soundcloud.com/hardwell/coldplay-sky-full-of-stars-hardwell-remix-download.

I read that `/resolve` was a good approach to get the trackid but it's not working. I get `403 Forbidden` in the console.

```
SC.get('/resolve/?url=https://soundcloud.com/hardwell/coldplay-sky-full-of-stars-hardwell-remix-download&client_id=3596a42d6242b9c1ee76740a7771d33a', function(track) {
  console.log(track); // returns null
});
```

Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/amwill/pen/grXNrB). Please help me load this track for my basic SoundCloud SDK audio player. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct and even works with some tracks, for example the ones from the documentation.

You're encountering a problem that I found personally should be emphasized in their documentation. The API access for this track has been disabled (even if the widget is enabled), therefore your have not right to query this track using the API and it returns a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code.

This is described in the `Linked Services` part of the [SoundCloud terms of use](https://soundcloud.com/terms-of-use):

> You can limit and restrict the availability of certain of Your Content to other users of the Platform, and to users of Linked Services, at any time using the permissions tab in the track edit section for each sound you upload, subject to the provisions of the Disclaimer section below.

You can check in your code if any error like this one was encountered while fetching the track informations and depending on the success or failure, continue with the correct action:

```
var clientId = 'CLIENT_ID';

SC.initialize({
  client_id: clientId
});

var songUrl = 'https://soundcloud.com/hardwell/coldplay-sky-full-of-stars-hardwell-remix-download';

SC.get('/resolve?url=' + songUrl + '&client_id=' + clientId, function(data, error) {
  if (error === null) {
    console.log('Do something like playing the song.');
  } else {
    console.log('Print an error message?');
  }
});
```

Comment: ah i see. i guess my plan won't work that way. thanks for your answer!